# Inverted proportion

Tags: javascript, math

I have information that

```
1X = 98 N
98X = 0.01020408163265306 N
```

How can I calculate number N based on number X from range 1 to 98, knowing that when number `X=1` is equal `N=98` and when `X=98` then `N=0.01020408163265306`

Maybe it is silly, but how to write function to calculate number N from X ?

Comment: Is it a linear relationship? This seems like high school or college algebra.

Comment: Once you determine the formula from algebra, it should be simple to translate that into a JS function.

Comment: Perhaps enlighten me, surely it is high school algebra, something mostly useless for 99.9% people. I just forgot how to do it. It doesn't look linear

Comment: Without knowing anything about the relationship, there is no unique solution. Try to visualize the problem in a 2D coordinate system, where the horizontal axis is your `X` variable and the vertical axis is your `N` variable. You have two points at `(1, 98)` and `(98, 0.01)`. What can you say about the space between these points?

Comment: If it's linear, do you remember the formula for slope from geometry? If none of this is meaningful to you, you should be asking in [math.se].

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks, that was good idea. I can probe more points, I have assembled chart https://i.imgur.com/W6ZQoud.png However, I am still unsure how to figure out exact function and factor by which I can change angle of it.

Comment: @Barmar I understand your point of view, this is first time since 15 years that my math knowledge was needed, after all I can research it now.

Comment: From the plot and the numbers it looks like you might be looking for `N = 98/(X^2)`

Comment: the equations provided are two different lines which only intersects at 0. you can calculate N from X individually from each equation.

Comment: Thank you @Presquevu. Completely agreed. Thanks all for help, I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Now that you've posted more [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/empyk.png), I'll amend my answer to say that this function does a pretty good job of approximating the data you provided:

```
y = 100*exp(-x/3.5)
```

I guessed a form that uses the exponential function.  The value at zero is clear, as is the value when x becomes large.  I guessed a time constant that gave a good visual fit.

Comment: Yup, it's an educational site.  Lots of developers have poor math backgrounds.  Nothing wrong with helping them.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as a fractional function; 
Result = N/(X squared)

Hopefully this is what you were looking for. But if you want N to be a function of X:

N = 1/X, which *is* an inverse function.